# How to convert Audio buffer to MP3 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, mediastream

I am using MediaRecorder in ReactJS to record audio from the microphone and storing into the blob with MIME type "audio/mp3". I want to convert this blob to MP3 and upload it in S3 bucket.

I am able to convert it into WAV by using audioContext, decodeAudioData and audioBufferToWav functions, but the size of the WAV is very large. Since the MP3 file has relatively very small in size so I want it to convert my blob to MP3. Any help?

My code for recording and converting to wav:

```
getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(stream => {
        this.stream = stream;
        const mimeType = 'audio/mp3';
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        const audioChunks = [];
        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
            type: mimeType});

        });
      }).catch(error => { });
```

Converting above created blob to WAV:

```
const reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      let base64 = reader.result + '';
      base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
      const ab = new ArrayBuffer(base64.length);
      const buff = new Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');
      const view = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (let i = 0; i < buff.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buff[i];
      }
      const context = new AudioContext();
      context.decodeAudioData(ab, (buffer) => {
      const wavFile = toWav(buffer);
}
```

I am storing `wavFile` into the S3. I want MP3, please help?

Answer (score 11):

This is how I combined `MediaRecorder` and Format converter based on great CuriousChad answer. Just needed to consider MP3 encoder as Stereo to work.

First, set AudioFormat equals to 'WEBM' (Chrome), 'MP3', or 'WAV':

```js
this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
  if (AudioFormat === "MP3" || AudioFormat === "WAV") {
    var data = this.chunks[0];
    var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: "video/webm" });

    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // Set up file reader on loaded end event
    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
      const arrayBuffer = fileReader.result; // as ArrayBuffer;

      // Convert array buffer into audio buffer
      audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, (audioBuffer) => {
        // Do something with audioBuffer
        console.log(audioBuffer);
        var MP3Blob = audioBufferToWav(audioBuffer);
        onStop(MP3Blob, audioBuffer);
      });
    };

    //Load blob
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  } else {
    var data = this.chunks[0];
    var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: "audio/mpeg" });
    onStop(blob, data);
  }
  this.chunks = [];
};
```

Second, convert Buffer to Wav:

```js
function audioBufferToWav(aBuffer) {
  let numOfChan = aBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    btwLength = aBuffer.length * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
    btwArrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(btwLength),
    btwView = new DataView(btwArrBuff),
    btwChnls = [],
    btwIndex,
    btwSample,
    btwOffset = 0,
    btwPos = 0;
  setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
  setUint32(btwLength - 8); // file length - 8
  setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"
  setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
  setUint32(16); // length = 16
  setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
  setUint16(numOfChan);
  setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate);
  setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
  setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
  setUint16(16); // 16-bit
  setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
  setUint32(btwLength - btwPos - 4); // chunk length

  for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < aBuffer.numberOfChannels; btwIndex++)
    btwChnls.push(aBuffer.getChannelData(btwIndex));

  while (btwPos < btwLength) {
    for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < numOfChan; btwIndex++) {
      // interleave btwChnls
      btwSample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, btwChnls[btwIndex][btwOffset])); // clamp
      btwSample =
        (0.5 + btwSample < 0 ? btwSample * 32768 : btwSample * 32767) | 0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
      btwView.setInt16(btwPos, btwSample, true); // write 16-bit sample
      btwPos += 2;
    }
    btwOffset++; // next source sample
  }

  let wavHdr = lamejs.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(btwArrBuff));

  //Stereo
  let data = new Int16Array(btwArrBuff, wavHdr.dataOffset, wavHdr.dataLen / 2);
  let leftData = [];
  let rightData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    leftData.push(data[i]);
    rightData.push(data[i + 1]);
  }
  var left = new Int16Array(leftData);
  var right = new Int16Array(rightData);

  if (AudioFormat === "MP3") {
    //STEREO
    if (wavHdr.channels === 2)
      return wavToMp3Stereo(
        wavHdr.channels,
        wavHdr.sampleRate,
        left,
        right,
      );
    //MONO
    else if (wavHdr.channels === 1)
      return wavToMp3(wavHdr.channels, wavHdr.sampleRate, data);
  } else return new Blob([btwArrBuff], { type: "audio/wav" });

  function setUint16(data) {
    btwView.setUint16(btwPos, data, true);
    btwPos += 2;
  }

  function setUint32(data) {
    btwView.setUint32(btwPos, data, true);
    btwPos += 4;
  }
}
```

Third, convert WAV to MP3:

I had to switch to Stereo as I have 2 channels for MP3Encoder left & right.

```js
function wavToMp3(channels, sampleRate, left, right = null) {
  var buffer = [];
  var mp3enc = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(channels, sampleRate, 128);
  var remaining = left.length;
  var samplesPerFrame = 1152;

  for (var i = 0; remaining >= samplesPerFrame; i += samplesPerFrame) {
    if (!right) {
      var mono = left.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
      var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(mono);
    } else {
      var leftChunk = left.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
      var rightChunk = right.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
      var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(leftChunk, rightChunk);
    }
    if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
      buffer.push(mp3buf); //new Int8Array(mp3buf));
    }
    remaining -= samplesPerFrame;
  }
  var d = mp3enc.flush();
  if (d.length > 0) {
    buffer.push(new Int8Array(d));
  }

  var mp3Blob = new Blob(buffer, { type: "audio/mp3" });
  //var bUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3Blob);

  // send the download link to the console
  //console.log('mp3 download:', bUrl);
  return mp3Blob;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I'm confused as to where this.chunks is coming from in your first part of the example

Comment: @Polyline I got this error RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView on Mac

Comment: lamejs is not defined

Answer (score 10):

I'm not using the ReactJS MediaRecorder nor do I exactly follow what's going on in your specific example, but I have a solution for converting an AudioBuffer to an mp3, way of wave.

The first function is based on [russellgood.com/how-to-convert-audiobuffer-to-audio-file](https://www.russellgood.com/how-to-convert-audiobuffer-to-audio-file/). The second is based on [lamejs](https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs).

## First, convert the AudioBuffer to a wave blob

```
function audioBufferToWav(aBuffer) {
    let numOfChan = aBuffer.numberOfChannels,
        btwLength = aBuffer.length * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
        btwArrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(btwLength),
        btwView = new DataView(btwArrBuff),
        btwChnls = [],
        btwIndex,
        btwSample,
        btwOffset = 0,
        btwPos = 0;
    setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
    setUint32(btwLength - 8); // file length - 8
    setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"
    setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
    setUint32(16); // length = 16
    setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
    setUint16(numOfChan);
    setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate);
    setUint32(aBuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
    setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
    setUint16(16); // 16-bit
    setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
    setUint32(btwLength - btwPos - 4); // chunk length

    for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < aBuffer.numberOfChannels; btwIndex++)
        btwChnls.push(aBuffer.getChannelData(btwIndex));

    while (btwPos < btwLength) {
        for (btwIndex = 0; btwIndex < numOfChan; btwIndex++) {
            // interleave btwChnls
            btwSample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, btwChnls[btwIndex][btwOffset])); // clamp
            btwSample = (0.5 + btwSample < 0 ? btwSample * 32768 : btwSample * 32767) | 0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
            btwView.setInt16(btwPos, btwSample, true); // write 16-bit sample
            btwPos += 2;
        }
        btwOffset++; // next source sample
    }

    let wavHdr = lamejs.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(btwArrBuff));
    let wavSamples = new Int16Array(btwArrBuff, wavHdr.dataOffset, wavHdr.dataLen / 2);

    wavToMp3(wavHdr.channels, wavHdr.sampleRate, wavSamples);

    function setUint16(data) {
        btwView.setUint16(btwPos, data, true);
        btwPos += 2;
    }

    function setUint32(data) {
        btwView.setUint32(btwPos, data, true);
        btwPos += 4;
    }
}
```

## Second, convert the wave to an mp3

```
function wavToMp3(channels, sampleRate, samples) {
    var buffer = [];
    var mp3enc = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(channels, sampleRate, 128);
    var remaining = samples.length;
    var samplesPerFrame = 1152;
    for (var i = 0; remaining >= samplesPerFrame; i += samplesPerFrame) {
        var mono = samples.subarray(i, i + samplesPerFrame);
        var mp3buf = mp3enc.encodeBuffer(mono);
        if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
            buffer.push(new Int8Array(mp3buf));
        }
        remaining -= samplesPerFrame;
    }
    var d = mp3enc.flush();
    if(d.length > 0){
        buffer.push(new Int8Array(d));
    }

    var mp3Blob = new Blob(buffer, {type: 'audio/mp3'});
    var bUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3Blob);

    // send the download link to the console
    console.log('mp3 download:', bUrl);

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You just saved me hours of research. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is a great solution, but in my testing audio recorded in Firefox cannot be converted to an mp3.  The solution by @polyline works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.