# Supabase uploaded audio blobs not playing

Tags: javascript, database, next.js, blob, supabase

I'm using Supabase storage to store audio blobs. The blob is returned from an API call and once returned it is uploaded. I can see the file in my storage bucket with the file type of audio/mpeg and a size associated however when I press play nothing happens and the length of the audio is 0:00. When I manually upload a mp3 file I see a length like 1:29 and the file plays. Below is the code that does it. I know the api works because I call it on my client side and the audio plays. I'm trying to save blobs to a database to prevent unnecessary API calls.

```
const getAudio = async (message) => {
console.log("called");
const data = {
  text: "hi",
  voice_settings: {
    stability: 0,
    similarity_boost: 0,
  },
};

const config = {
  headers: {
    "xi-api-key": process.env.API_KEY,
  },
  responseType: "blob",
};
try {
  const voiceResponse = await axios.post(
    "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/XXXXXXXXXXX",
    data,
    config
  );

  console.log(voiceResponse.data);

  blob = new Blob([voiceResponse.data], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
  console.log("=========================================");
  console.log(blob);

  const response = await supabase.storage
    .from("audio_blobs")
    .upload(email + "/" + "audio.mp3", blob, {
      contentType: "audio/mpeg",
    });

  if (response.error) {
    console.log(response.error);
  } else {
    console.log("success");
  }

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

};
getAudio()

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload):

> For React Native, using either Blob, File or FormData does not work as intended. Upload file using ArrayBuffer from base64 file data instead, see example below.

So, you'll need to get the file as mp3, then use an array buffer:

```
import { decode } from 'base64-arraybuffer'
// (...)
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('email'+ "/" + "audio.mp3", decode('mp3_file'), {
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg'
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the implementation is in react not react native but I'm willing to give it a try. The api returns a blob, how would I get the file as mp3 to then use the buffer as suggested above?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63344988

Answer (score 0):

To save audio blobs in your supabase bucket you can create a supabase client in your component and upload the audio file from there.

Setting up supabase client:

```js
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabase = createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || " ",
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY || " "
);
```

Sending audio folder:

```js
const file = new File(recordingBuffer, "recording.mp3", {
    type: recordingBlob.type,
});

const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from("Recordings")
    .upload("clientside", file, {
        contentType: "audio/mpeg",
    });
```