# creating a script in p5.js web that takes a song, slices it and uses the slices randomly to generate a new song. how can i save the new song as .mp3?

Tags: audio, p5.js, p5.sound.js

i'm creating a program that from an input .mp3 file song generate fragments with 100 millisecond length, than randomly reassemble the fragments to create a new song output. for the moment everything works but i don't know how to make the program generate a .mp3/.wav file to be saved in the "/output" folder that i have create in my p5.js sketch.
this is my code:

```
let audioBuffer;
let segmentLength = 100; // length of each segment in milliseconds
let patternLength = 15; // length of each pattern in segments
let numPatterns; // number of patterns in the final output
let numSegments; // total number of segments in the output
let segments = [];
let patterns = [];
let audioContext;

function preload() {
  audioFile = loadSound('sounds/02ContortYourself.mp3', onAudioLoaded);
}

function onAudioLoaded() {
  // Create a new AudioContext object
  audioContext = new AudioContext();
  
  // Get the decoded audio buffer from the loaded audio file
  audioBuffer = audioFile.buffer;
  
  // Calculate the maximum number of patterns and segments that fit within 1 minute
  let maxDuration = 60; // maximum duration of the output song in seconds
  numPatterns = Math.floor(maxDuration * 1000 / (segmentLength * patternLength));
  numSegments = numPatterns * patternLength;
  
  // Split the audio buffer into segments of the specified length, up to the maximum duration
  for(let i = 0; i < numSegments; i++) {
    let go = i * segmentLength / 1000;
    let end = go + segmentLength / 1000;
    let segment = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).subarray(go * audioBuffer.sampleRate, end * audioBuffer.sampleRate);
    segments.push(segment);
    
    // Print the length of the segment in milliseconds
    console.log(`Segment ${i}: ${segmentLength}ms`);
  }
  
  // Shuffle the segments array using the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
  for (let i = segments.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [segments[i], segments[j]] = [segments[j], segments[i]];
  }
  
  // Group segments into patterns
  for (let i = 0; i < numPatterns; i++) {
    let pattern = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < patternLength; j++) {
      pattern.push(segments[i * patternLength + j]);
    }
    patterns.push(pattern);
  }
  
  // Arrange patterns in a specific sequence
  let patternSequence = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1]; // example pattern sequence
  let outputSegments = [];
  while (outputSegments.length < numSegments) {
    outputSegments = outputSegments.concat(patternSequence.map(index => patterns[index]).flat());
  }
  outputSegments = outputSegments.slice(0, numSegments);
  
  // Create a new audio buffer for the output song
  let outputBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
    numberOfChannels: 1,
    length: outputSegments.length * segmentLength * audioBuffer.sampleRate / 1000,
    sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate
  });
  
  // Copy each segment into the output buffer in their arranged order
  for (let i = 0; i < outputSegments.length; i++) {
    let offset = i * segmentLength * audioBuffer.sampleRate / 1000;
    outputBuffer.copyToChannel(outputSegments[i], 0, offset);
  }
  
  // Create a new audio source from the output buffer and play it
  let outputSource = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, { buffer: outputBuffer });
  outputSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
  outputSource.start();
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}
```

the function outputSource.start(); makes the new song playing but what i want is the song to saved in the /output folder not to be played. i'm stack here and i don't know how to go on.

thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264581/how-to-convert-audio-buffer-to-mp3-in-javascript